# Anonymous email verification system - similar to an anonymous tip system

Tags: forms, security, email, web, anonymity

I want to create an anonymous tip system that verifies a user's email address without saving it.

The point would be to verify that someone is affiliated with a certain organization through their email address (whether it be a .gov or a .edu or a particular website's address).

Ideally, however, the email address would not be saved anywhere so that the individual could still comfortably submit their tip/complaint in a totally anonymous and secure way. I suppose we could also be open to encryption, but ideally somehow we would be blind to the user's email address.

What would be the best way to implement this if you have no constraints (it could be an email system, PHP, whatever)?

Comment: What of the email address remains in the system?  Just the domain?  Do you need to be able to verify that a tip was submitted with an email address or with an address from a domain when presented with the email address/domain at a later date?

Comment: Are you worried about attackers who can observe email sent in the clear or access the tipsters mailbox?

Comment: Why and how would you convince users that you can send them email but not remember their address? Even if your code is hosted by a third party there are obvious questions that I as a user would find hard to answer convincingly.

Comment: @Mike Ideally none of the email address remains in the system - possibly just the domain. The tip mostly just needs to be verified initially, but later reference of where the tip came from in a broad sense could be possibly valuable.

Comment: Also, if you need them to use their work email, how could you possibly hope to prevent their boss / sysadmin from reading their email and, say, keep a copy of the verification link?

Comment: That's actually a great point. We would tell users about that risk and advise them to delete the email then. I know that this still poses a potential risk even if it's delete. Is there a best way to approach this situation in general or at least a good way to execute it while minimizing risk?

Comment: @user3485818, No.  Deleting an email doesn't necessarily remove it from the system.  The only things that causes an organization to promptly delete email is an SLA and lawyers with a data retention policy.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Got it. Good to know. I'll change the scenario a little then. If we want to simply avoid anyone with access to our system alone from directly knowing the email of anyone who registers or submits a story what would be a possible way we could approach this? Thanks again for your advice and challenges!

Comment: security.stackexchange might be a good place for this.  They can help refine your question, and if your problem turns out to be one of preserving confidentiality & [non-repudiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) they'll know more about the right ways to employ crypto than SO.

Comment: Email, by default, does not provide any authentication on the From field.  As a result, it is frequently possible to spoof the sender field, rendering this entire scheme pointless.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

Comment: Even if the message is gone from their inbox, there will be logs and possibly captured packets simewhere en route. There is simply no way to ensure that an employee can be sure that no trace of an email s/he received is left in the system.

Comment: @aurand but clicking on a "yes, it's me, I requested this" link in an incoming email *to* that address is reasonable proof that the address belongs to the person who initiated the transaction.

Comment: @tripleee, The difference between "belongs to" and "is controlled by" can be important, especially when botnets contain machines with POP3/exchange mailboxes.  That an unguessable URL was fetched is only evidence that the transaction was initiated by someone who owns/pwns the mailbox, or can act as a MITM on the route to the mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'll change the scenario a little then. If we want to simply avoid anyone with access to our system alone from directly knowing the email of anyone who registers or submits a story what would be a possible way we could approach this?

The best way is to never store any part of the email.

Assuming you do need to be able to tell, given the email/hostname again, whether it was associated with a tip, then just treat the email/hostname as you would any sensitive secret like a password.  [Salt and hash it](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt).

That an email address has lower-entropy than a password shouldn't matter as long as you generate good salts.

Answer (score 0):

If I was a whistleblower who wanted to submit information about my employer to anyone, I would make absolutely sure that no part of the transaction involved any facility under my employer's control -- equipment, communications, or people. That's the only way I could be reasonably convinced that my anonymity could not be trivially subverted.